# Callable statement is not finishing its execution but the same procedure gets executed fully

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I got a problem regarding stored procedure execution. Whenever i am executing a procedure from thick client system, which generally takes more than an hour or even more, the `callableStatement.execute()` is getting stuck. i.e, in the back-end the procedure gets completed but the system still shows in running mode. I have checked on the back-end and noticed that the last line of the procedure is also executed. What could be the possible reason for this?

I am using Oracle 11g and ojdbc6 driver.

The following parameters are set on the database for the profiles created:

```
IDLE_TIME = UNLIMITED
CONNECT_TIME = UNLIMITED
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after so many assumptions, I got the solution. Actually the app server and db server network issue. The problem was coming when the network gets down just after the `callableStatement.execute()`. Sometime it was throwing "socket error" otherwise it was getting stuck even after completion of procedure.